# SimpleDateFormatter returns two different time zones

Tags: java, datetime, time, simpledateformat, dst

I have these two strings as input strings

```
03/12/16
03/14/16
```

I make a **single SimpleDateFormatter** object to get the date difference like this

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy",Locale.US);
Date dateChkIn = formatter.parse("03/12/16");
System.out.println("Checkin date at nights check - "+dateChkIn.toString());
Date dateChkOut = formatter.parse("03/14/16");
System.out.println("Checkout date at nights check - "+dateChkOut.toString());
Long numberOfNghtsCalc = ((dateChkOut.getTime() - dateChkIn.getTime()) / 86400000L);
System.out.println("number of nigts calculated - "+ numberOfNghtsCalc);
```

Below is my output in the server

```
Checkin date at nights check - Sat Mar 12 00:00:00 EST 2016
Checkout date at nights check - Mon Mar 14 00:00:00 EDT 2016
number of nigts calculated - 1
```

Expected output is **number of nigts calculated - 2**
Please note the two different Time Zones which returned from the formatter

Update : 
13-Mar-2016 is considered as DST changing date. Therefore my calculation is getting wrong. (*divide by 86400000L*)

Comment: Start by using either Java 8's Time API or JodaTime to calculate the difference between dates ... did you happen to cross over a daylight savings boundary?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I appreciate your comment. But my system is using Java 1.5 . This code is in my production environment. All these time; it worked perfectly. Suddenly this was occured.

Comment: Well, Joda-Time supports Java 5, but you could even use `Calendar`

Comment: try add `formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` below the `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @cwfei It might not work. All servers are set to US time zone. EDT. I want to do all calculations upon that.

Comment: you may read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I found the solution.*** I got to know that best solution would be use Joda Time. But with least change in the existing code, I think this tricky way will be better. Please edit this answer if you see any drawbacks.

```
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(dateChkIn);

    Date result = null;
    while (calendar.getTime().before(dateChkOut)){
            result = calendar.getTime();


            dates.add(result);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    System.out.println("DAYS CALCULATED BY NEW SOLUTION: " + dates.size());
    newNumberOfNghtsCalc = (long) dates.size();
    dates.clear();
```

This has actually reduced the running time!

Time taken for code in Question : 275000 (in nano seconds)

Time taken for New solution: 103000

Answer (score 1):

on next 13 March 2016 change hour by EST to EDT. So `SimpleDateFormat` takes care of this change.

Go [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york)

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know much about **Daylight saving time**. This issue was reported in our production. Should I need to do any code level changes to handle this? Is this a very rare occation? How should I inform this to my US client?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan: Not rare! Every year you have the same issue when change EST -> EDT and viceversa. The same issue you have if you work with different time zone (i.e. Europe vs America).

Comment: But my question is why **SimpleDateFomatter**  returned two different timezones ? EST for 12th and EDT for 16th ?

Comment: @Jude: SimpleDateFormatter returns the same time zone, but time zone change in that area. So SDF is sensible to this change.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is of caused by the **Daylight Saving Time, which for 2016 is scheduled as March 13, 2016**. Here you can read a short article on the difference between [EDT and EST](http://www.prnewswire.com/blog/mind-your-s-and-ds-answering-the-edt-vs-est-question-1502.html).

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

I recommend you use the modern, `java.time` date-time API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate dateChkIn = LocalDate.parse("03/12/16", dtf);
        LocalDate dateChkOut = LocalDate.parse("03/14/16", dtf);
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateChkIn, dateChkOut);
        System.out.println(days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).